# CH340G set of chip partially working

Tags: usb, serial, converter

I bought quite a number of these [CH340G](https://www.insidegadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ch340g-datasheet.pdf) USB-to-UART chips for a project. I initially mounted them on PCB and soon discovered some of them are working and others don't.

To help me testing each individual chip I made a small tester with socket. I can easily insert a chip and see if it works or not. It turns out that on 50 units only 15 of them are working.

Before blaming who provided the chip I want to make sure I have everything right on my setup. I would need your help to identify what could be the cause of this.

Here is a picture of my tester which I have confirm is working correctly. (since I tested some chip as working with it).

[image: ch340G tester]

This is just usb on one side. Then there is a atmega328p that send serial data every half second. (just some random analogread).
This way I can connect the tester to a usb port and if I read the serial data I can assume the chip is working. Nothing more complicated.

The circuit diagram for the tester is shown here below.

[image: circuit diagram]

There is not much to connect to the CH340G. The CH340G is the two 8 pin connectors at the bottom right. This is where I plug my soic socket in.

Now comes the actual testing. I am using ubuntu for the test. I have tested non working chip both on ubuntu and windows and the result are the same. I will show the result on ubuntu because it is easier there.

When I connect the usb cable everything goes well. I get the following message on dmesg.

```
[26120.970957] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 30 using ehci-pci
[26121.080363] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[26121.080367] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26121.080370] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB Serial
[26121.080790] ch341 2-1.3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[26121.081807] usb 2-1.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I do have the ttyUSB0 available.

```
$ ls /dev/ttyUSB*
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

I can start and read the incoming data with the plain cat command.

```
$ stty -echo -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw speed 38400
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

This result in the serial port being read for 4 or 5 second then stops. Here is the message that I get once it fails.

```
[26367.035806] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[26367.036137] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
[26367.091788] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 30
[26367.094118] usb 2-1.3: failed to send control message: -19
[26367.094324] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[26367.094349] ch341 2-1.3:1.0: device disconnected
[26367.388301] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
[26367.497807] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[26367.497811] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26367.497814] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB Serial
[26367.498287] usb 2-1.3: can't set config #1, error -32
[26367.603781] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 31
[26377.296663] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 32 using ehci-pci
[26377.414119] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
[26377.414123] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[26377.414125] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB Serial
[26377.414685] ch341 2-1.3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[26377.416632] usb 2-1.3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I have also done the same reading with cutecom or the serial tool of arduino and results are the same.

If you have any ideas how I can solve this that you be great. Am I missing something in the diagram?
ANy particular comment about this error? **usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32**

It looks like the read makes the chip collapse for some reason.
What about unconnected pins on the CH340G? Should I treat them differently?

Did you also purchase CH340G chips where only 30% of them are working?

**EDIT**
As asked the picture of the PCB of the tester then the project itself.

[image: tester PCB]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us what your PCB designs look like - specifically the layout of the USB D+ & D- tracks between the USB connector and the CH340, for both your 'real' PCB as well as the tester?

Comment: Where did you buy your devices from?

Comment: Noted for the PCB pictures. Will come soon.
I initially bought some from aliexpress. When I found some of them not working I ordered more from LCSC who are more reliable. However I have the same problem with what they provided. China is the only place to get these specific chip I am afraid.

Comment: So the problem you're seeing is almost certainly related to the layout on your PCBs. You *must* route the USB D+ & D- lines together as a pair on the same side of the board. Most of the USB communication takes place as balanced differential signaling, and you need to treat those tracks as a transmission line. For short distances (an inch or 2) and no faster then "full speed" (12MBps) it'll probably be fine if you just run them both next to each other on the same side of the board without worrying too much about the exact characteristic impedance of the pair.

Comment: Ok I see. So these two tracks must be the same length and stick together as much as possible. Is that right? I will redo the tester layout and see if it improves. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @user290017 bear in mind you socket can ruin the signal too, you may want to test everything with soldering the IC onto PCB. As a side note: some CH340 don't need external crystal, so that you know (C/B/E versions; same pinout)

Comment: yes I am aware of this. Hmm I'll have to look into the crystal free chip. Thanks for that.

Comment: With multiple SMPS power sources , you may have possible  USB ground loop with CM noise.   Rule that out by shunting 0V to PE or use hand to USB cable to PE gnd.  Or use RF cap to PE.

Comment: I have found this video with someone having the same issue. https://youtu.be/9x4II5niaFU In the end he solved it by replacing the ch340 chip. I will certainly review my routing and pcb layout but I am dubious. I still give more probability to bad chips being sold. I hope I am wrong. Why some chip just work solidly while other totally fail. If it was for CM noise then they would all fail wouldn't they?

Comment: Some positive progress. I actually found an older PCB that I made in the past which (by accident) has both D+ and D- properly traced together. I took a chip that somewhat failed on my tester and soldered it to that PCB. Then it worked there. Excellent. I start to believe more in the pcb layout issue now.

Comment: Did you make sure the pins of the CH340 make good contact with the IC socket? Corroded/oxidized pins, maybe? In that case they would still work when soldered on a pcb.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't ever be your job to test chips for basic functionality as an end user, unless your time is worth nothing. That's the job of the factory. Buy your chips from a reputable source like DigiKey, Element14/Newark/RS Components, Allied Electronics, AVNET or the like.

You're buying junk. I've never ever, not even once, had to make a chip tester just to test brand new chips destined for a project or production, obtained from authorized distributors.

The truth is, unless you go directly to the factory, you just can't reliably source CH340G. That's probably all there's to it. As far as actually using it, it's an imaginary product. People who make volume products using it are getting it at the factory or lose money. You can do the same, or just choose a more sensible chip. Like, for example, any Atmel or small ARM microcontroller with USB device peripheral. It can emulate any device you want, and the libraries implementing the common CDC "virtual serial" device are available. It's much cheaper than dealing with dubious chips and testing them...

Comment: LCSC has almost 70,000 CH340G in stock and are Western-friendly. There are other trusted distributors in Asia. What you should not do is buy them (or any other part, for that matter) from unknown sources on Aliexpress or eBay.

Comment: I might have to come to that conclusion if the re-routing option fails. Although the ch340 is only found on Chinese market. I wish I could get them from digikey.
That means I would have to change the chip of my project. For now this chip is so cheap that even a 60% failure still put the chip at a good price (totally not the way we want this to happen I agree).

Comment: @user290017 The thing is: this is not a go/no-go test. Chips aren't binary devices that either work or don't work. The "good" chips may stop working when you warm them up, or cool them down, or at the supply voltage limits, or after aging for 1 year, or they may "work" but have marginal I/O signal levels or USB drive strength or USB signal capture range, etc. Without a full production-line test equivalent, you cannot know that the chips actually work. Just because they work in particular conditions and a particular USB cable and PC, it means very little, and you may waste time later...